# ¿Cómo insertar hipervínculos en GtkTextView?

Tags: c, interfaz-gráfica, gtk

Estoy buscando una forma de insertar hipervínculos en un `GtkTextView`. Sé que puedo insertar un `GtkLinkButton` o algún otro widget que admita eventos (un `GtkTextLabel` adentro de un `GtkEventBox`, por ejemplo), pero al usar estas opciones, el texto pierde cierta flexibilidad, y a su vez no se alinea correctamente. Por esto creo que la mejor opción sería insertar el texto del enlace y aplicarle un estilo específico (cosa que ya logré). Pero no encuentro la forma de "captar" los eventos y relacionarlos con la dirección del enlace mediante "callbacks".

¿Es esto posible? Si es así, ¿cómo se tendría que realizar? Si no, ¿hay alguna alternativa?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, es importante que revises [ask], recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste , saludos.

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, lo que intenté lo menciono en la pregunta, y la "investigación" está basada en la documentación oficial, algunos foros y el mismo StackOverflow en inglés. Si está faltando algún dato no sabría decir cuál es... ¿Aunque no sé si tal vez la pregunta pueda ser marcada como "Basada en opinión"?. De cualquier modo creo que di con la respuesta, la publicaré aquí en cuanto compruebe su usabilidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de un poco de investigación, di con la respuesta. Y puede parecer reinventar la rueda, pero al propósito de mi programa funciona perfectamente:

- Para empezar, almaceno todos los enlaces en una lista de `struct`s como la siguiente:

```c
typedef struct link link;

struct link
{
    char* url;
    int start;
    int end;
    link next;
};
```

- En `start` y `end` almaceno las posiciones de inicio y fin del enlace en el `GtkTextBuffer`.
- Entonces conecto una función *"callback"* a la señal `"button-press-event"`.
- Cuando el ususario hace click en el `GtkTextView`, la función obtiene la posición en el `GtkTextBuffer` del click usando las funciones [`gtk_text_view_window_to_buffer_coords`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html#gtk-text-view-window-to-buffer-coords) y [`gtk_text_view_get_iter_at_location`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html#gtk-text-view-get-iter-at-location), itera sobre la lista de enlaces, y si detecta que tal posición está en el rango (`start`, `end`), llama a otra función para procesar y abrir el enlace.